# Error al intentar actualizar una celda de un registro que contiene un contadoor

Tags: sql, tsql

Error al intentar actualizar una celda de un registro que contiene un contador.

Existe una tabla llamada Consultas que contiene las siguientes propiedades

- id (id del registro)
- id_hostname   (nombre del host)
- dia_trabajado(fecha en que trabajo)
- consultas_max ( 1.000.000 de consultas diaras)
- consultas_hechas (inicia con un valor de 0)

Existe n cantidad de `host` trabajando a la misma vez, donde estos realizan inserts o updates, tengo que lograr llevar el control de las consultas que realiza cada host por día.

```sql
update dbo.Consultas
set consultas_hechas = (select sum(consultas_hechas + 1))
where dia_trabajado = '2023-03-21' 
and id_hostname = 1
```

Error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La asignación a consultas_hechas, tiene que ser un valor escalar. Puedes obtenerlo realizando una subconsulta.

```
update dbo.Consultas 
set consultas_hechas = 
        ( Select sum(consultas_hechas) + 1 as total
        From dbo.Consultas
        where dia_Trabjado = '20230321'
            And id_HOSTNAME = 1
        )
where dia_trabajado = '20230321' 
and id_hostname = 1;
```